# mat-form-field select button background color apllies to all div instead of the button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have one select button from angular material, that I am trying to apply the background color of white, but when I do, all the div stays white and not only the div.

I tried to select the select button pieces by piece and apply the color of white, but the button has a lot of pierces and I must doing something wrong because it shouldn't be like this.

this is my button with a white background:

[image: 1]

html :

```
 <mat-form-field style="background-color: white">
          <mat-select placeholder="Zone" (selectionChange)="updatePlayerZone($event)" style="font-family: beaufort, serif;font-size: 16px">
            <mat-option value="br">BR</mat-option>
            <mat-option value="eune">EUNE</mat-option>
          </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

What should I add to only get the background of the button white and not all the div?

PS: yes the `div` don't have `background-color`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you clarify what you mean by: 'all the div stays white and not only the div.' and also in the image you have provided which bit is the bit you are thinking of as the 'button'. Thanks.

Comment: you could try putting the full code so we can see what is happening with the error and reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try the following css and I think `ViewEncapsulation.None` is the important:

CSS:

```
.mat-form-field-wrapper .mat-form-field-flex {
  background-color: white;
}
```

TS:

```
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'form-field-appearance-example',
  templateUrl: 'form-field-appearance-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['form-field-appearance-example.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll encourage you to use [Angular Material's theming capabilities](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming) rather than turning encapsulation off,  using `!important` or `::ng-deep` (will deprecated soon), etc.

If you don't want to use a theme that you can move your overriding CSS to the global level (src/styles.scss) to avoid turning encapsulation off.

```
.mat-form-field-label{
  color:green !important;
}
.mat-form-field-underline{
  background-color:green !important;
}
```